# How to parse HTML with Python 3.8 xml.etree?

Tags: python, html, xml, elementtree

I need to parse HTML files with the Python 3.8 xml package. This must be possible because some of the `xml.etree.ElementTree` methods have parameters that take `"xml"` or `"html"` as a value, but I can't find an example of how it's done.

I get an exception when I try to parse the HTML file:

```
htmlRoot = etree.ElementTree.parse(filepathname).getroot()
```

The parser throws an "undefined entity" exception when it encounters an HTML entity. I assume this is because HTML entities are predefined, while XML entities are not.

As the statement shows, I'm using the default parser. Maybe there's an HTML parser but I haven't found one. I'm not even sure whether there *are* other parsers, or I'd have to roll my own.

I don't want to use Python's html package because I need to walk a complete parsed tree like `xml.etree` provides. The html package doesn't work that way.

I've found examples of parsing HTML with the lxml package, but lxml isn't part of the standard Python configuration. That's would be a problem for coworkers who don't know Python and need a "plug and play" application.

Comment: ElementTree is an XML tool. It cannot be used to process arbitrary HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
from html import escape, unescape
textXML = re.sub("\\&\\w+\\;", lambda x: escape(unescape(x.group(0))), text)
```

In python3.4+ you can use `html.unescape` to convert html5 entity references into the respective unicode characters. After that, any xml parser works.

Comment: This trick is not known to many and it solves different questions related to html entities. The questions are not identical.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank>1</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank>4</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
<country name="Panama">
    <rank>68</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
    <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
</country>
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

Read this for more detail
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: How your answer is related to the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Opoke Loveth, I appreciate your desire to help, but your answer doesn't have anything to do with the question. I hope you will read the question again and try again. Advice from anyone else is welcome.